# Why we use path.join and not use relative path to access public directory in express and node server running?

Tags: node.js, express, path.js

I don't get it, why we don't use relative path in our app instead of this path that we get after path.join. is it not possible to use relative path like express.static('../public')?

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const app = express();

const publicDir = path.join(__dirname,'../public')

app.use(express.static(publicDir));`
```

Answer (score 2):

If you use a relative path with `express.static()`, then it's relative to where you launched your app, not necessarily relative to `__dirname` which means that merely changing the directory from where you launch your app from could break your app.

If you build a full path using `__dirname`, then this aspect of your app won't break if you happen to launch your app from a different directory.  This is just more robust.  If you intend for the path to be relative to `__dirname`, then you may as well enforce that in your code.

Comment: @MuhammadWaqasIlyas - Did this answer your question?  If so, you can indicate that to the community by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer.  That will also earn you some reputation points here on stackoverflow.